# UITableView rotation behaving strange after Xcode 6 and iOS 8 update

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am working on an app since a while, it is going well. However, this weekend I updated to Xcode 6 and now my app is behaving differently as opposed to before the update to Xcode 6.

I have a UITableView in my app which I rotate in viewDidLoad:

```
//Rotate playerCardsTable.
CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
_playerCardsTable.transform = rotateTable;
_playerCardsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _playerCardsTable.frame.size.width, _playerCardsTable.frame.size.height);
```

In Xcode before the update (Xcode 5) I had this view:

[image]

But now, after updating to Xcode 6, I have this view:

[image]

The tableview is rotated, ergo I have horizontal scrolling, but it seems like the frame is not changed correctly after rotation. It is 320 pixels high and 80 pixels wide and it should be the other way round. I don't know why, but it seems I cannot change the frame afterwards in code, in other words, I don't see any change after changing the width and height.

The tableview is added via the interface builder and holds custom cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *cardName = [[[[[Game game] localPlayer] playerCards] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] fileNameCard];
cell.cardImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cardName];

Card *card;
card = [[[[Game game] localPlayer] playerCards] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(card.playable == IsPlayable){
    cell.backgroundColor = isPlayableColor;}
else if (card.playable == IsNotPlayable) {
    cell.backgroundColor = isNotPlayableColor;}
else if (card.playable == IsReallyPlayable) {
    cell.backgroundColor = isReallyPlayableColor;}


//Rotate image to align with rotated tableview.
CGAffineTransform rotateImage = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
cell.cardImage.transform = rotateImage;
cell.playableImage.transform = rotateImage;

cell.cardImage.layer.borderWidth = 2;
cell.cardImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
cell.cardImage.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.cardImage.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

cell.cardImage.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.cardImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
cell.cardImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
cell.cardImage.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
cell.cardImage.clipsToBounds = NO;

return cell;}
```

To be clear; I did not change any code after the update, so the different behavior is caused by the update.

Hope you guys could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar situation after upgrading iPad to ios8 just recently - Horizontal tables not appearing correctly.

I don't have a complete solution, but can tell you from research and testing that in my case it was due to the transform action and `AutoLayout` constraints on the `UITableView` not coordinating/cooperating. Evidently the way these two concepts work together changed somewhat in ios8.

A *top* constraint set in a storyboard becomes a *left* constraint after the transform (or right, never did figure it out properly).

Bottom line for me was that after trying a number of combinations of constraints, including removing them before transform, then adding constraints back in after the transform, I ended up converting from a `UITableView` to `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I did not get any responses, so I just added a new `UITableView` and worked from there. I think hou are right about the `AutoLayout` thoughts, but I just could not get it fixed. SO I started over with the `UITableView` and added new constraints, etc. Now it is working as expected. Thanks anyway!